# Use of anatomy data to map cauda equina nerve damage to guide therapy etc

Tags: graphics3d, anatomy

A question with very practical consequences for someone close to me who I would like to help in the aftermath of a massive L4/5 disk herniation leading to cauda equina syndrome and emergency neurosurgery (diskectomy).

I want to map areas of nerve damage, and sensitivity to movement in surrounding tissues, in order to identify causes of ongoing pain, track recovery, guide physical therapy etc.

Although I now have modest experience with MMA, based on a reading of the anatomy data and 3d graphics documentation this is so different from what I am comfortable with I have no idea where to begin and confess I can show no effort (using MMA 11.0.1, Win 10 64-bit)

I would like to do the following (since I am not medically trained I may also be missing e.g. important nerve types other than those carrying touch/temperature, but I'm sure you'll understand what I'm trying to achieve from these examples).

- On a 3D representation of the female body (which should therefore be "zoomable" to allow resolution ~0.5cm)

  - Mark points of skin contact (possibly distinguishing pressure & temperature sensation?), designating each point as e.g. touch/temperature (in)sensitive,
  - Mark/nominate certain muscles (including internals) in order to identify their enervating nerves
- Trace these nerves through the body and display

  - their paths through a 3D body image
  - slices (like MRI slices, with yaw, pitch roll, pan & zoom) through the body so that the 2D distribution of noted nerves can be examined in particular places.
- Save the points noted for comparison with a later set so that changes in sensation might indicate areas of nerve recovery

How much of this might be possible, what existing resources might I exploit, etc? Are there any existing non-MMA approaches to these issues??

All suggestions gratefully received,

Comment: Wanting to help your friend is admirable, but accomplishing all your goals in Mathematica is probably unrealistic.  Are you aware of software such as VisibleBody? (https://www.visiblebody.com/anatomy-and-physiology-apps/human-anatomy-atlas)

Comment: @ToddAllen I wasn't aware of that site but I will check it out. As for using Mathematica, I thought it at least worth asking, esp. given MMA's powerful region handling tools, nearest neighbour, graphics etc., and one never knows who has done what with it. Thanks for taking the time to offer your thoughts.

Comment: A start:  `Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftUpperLimb"]["Graphics3D"] /. 
 Annotation[x_, y_] :> Tooltip[x, y["Name"]]`